# mongodb codec registry error while trying to insert java enum

Tags: java, mongodb, enums

I have a class called Person.class where I have a enum called sex.

```
public enum Sex{
    Male,Female
}
```

And I have a variable to put this enum value.

```
private Sex sex = Sex.Male;

public Sex getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(Sex sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}
```

its inserting but when I try to update or retrieve it is throwing this error called

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class in.co.precisionit.pivot.database.model.Person$Sex.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
```

The update query:

```
collection.updateOne(eq("employeeList.user", employeeReference),set("user.$.sex", sex)).getModifiedCount();
```

The retrieve query:

```
Aggregates.unwind("$user");
Aggregates.match(eq("user.sex", sex));
Aggregates.group("$_id", Accumulators.push("user", "$user"));
collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(unwind, match, group)).first().getUser();
```

plz some help.

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this today.
This seems to be a bug in the 3.6.0 driver. There is a new version out (3.6.1), that does not seem to have this issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't see a newer version out there called 3.6.1

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/ does list it on their front page.
Also it's available via maven central.

Comment: it seems to be not working when updating and retrieving the enum. I have updated my question

Comment: I ran into this as well in 4.4.X and 4.5.X. It does not happen in 4.6.1.